# Error :write function in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have written a mysql function to check duplicate values in table. But instead return result of function, it returns number of rows in table. I don't know why and how to solve this problem. Please help me
here is my mysql funcion:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `check_duplicate`(tenMH varchar(45),
    thongtin varchar(45),mausac varchar(45),
    kichco varchar(45),giatran double,mancc int,madm int) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    declare result int default 0;

    select count(*) into result from  phpdb.mathang where (TenMH=tenMH) and (ThongTin=thongtin)
    and(MauSac=mausac) and(KichCo=kichco) and(GiaTran=giatran)and(MaNCC=mancc) and(MaDM=madm);

RETURN result;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returned exactly what it should do.

If you want to fetch those duplicate records you better go for a `PROCEDURE` but not a `FUNCTION`.

- **Functions** are to return a single row, single column results.
- **Procedures** can be defined to perform some operations and optionally return multi value and multi row outputs.

Convert your function to a procedure so that you can capture duplicate records as a resultset.

And as a precaution, input parameter names should have different naming convention than the table columns for restricting the name ambiguity.

Your procedure should be looking as follows:

```
drop procedure if exists get_duplicates;
delimiter //

create definer=`root`@`localhost` 
    procedure `get_duplicates`( 
        in _tenmh varchar(45),
        in _thongtin varchar(45),
        in _mausac varchar(45),
        in _kichco varchar(45),
        in _giatran double,
        in _mancc int,
        in _madm int )
begin
    select * from  phpdb.mathang 
     where tenmh    = _tenmh 
       and thongtin = _thongtin
       and mausac   = _mausac
       and kichco   = _kichco 
       and giatran  = _giatran
       and mancc    = _mancc
       and madm     = _madm;
end;

//

delimiter ;
```

**Refer to Documentation**:

- [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)